# Informix Help: Executing a TABLE Full of SELECTs

Tags: sql, select, eval, informix

If the one field in five-row *SelectTable* is *SelectStatement*, and each of the five rows houses a valid `SELECT`, how may I fire off any one of those rows' *SelectStatement*s?

This is akin to storing HTML in a SQL-database table and calling up those stored HTML strings on demand, to render (not on Informix, of course, but elsewhere) a Web-site page.

How do I make Informix render (execute) those stored `SELECT`s?

Comment: This is similar to your previous question, and the same issue arises: how are you going to deal with the variant types of data returned by the queries? Do all the queries return rows of data with the same type, or do they return different types? One option: client selects the query into a host variable on the client side, and then have the client code prepare the query, declare a cursor for the result set, describe the result set and allocate appropriate variables to receive the results, then open the cursor, repeatedly fetch rows, and finally close it — and free the statement and cursor.

Comment: Thank you, again, for your help!  Client-side programming languages would make this a breeze, but I may not use those:  The heavy lifting has to be on the Informix side.  I know that this is a similar question, but the title and different slant may help Informix newbies:  I could not find much relevant, specific-to-Informix help via Google.  What I figured out is that I could FOREACH through the SelectTable, in order to grab the desired SELECT string.  Then, EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SelectString.  -- CONTINUED IN COMMENT BELOW --

Comment: -- CONTINUED FROM COMMENT ABOVE --  One big catch, though:  For EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, the SelectString has to be a SELECT INTO (that is, into a temp or regular table...not a plain SELECT).

Comment: If you want results, you can't use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.  It is designed for statements that do not return results.  If you want results, you have to use a cursor — which leads to the PREPARE, DECLARE, OPEN, FETCH, CLOSE, FREE (and a second FREE) cycle in languages such as ESQL/C.  In SPL (and I4GL — Informix 4GL), you can use a FOREACH loop instead; it slightly reduces the workload on the programmer.